# SQL Server Sum Returning Invalid Number

Tags: sql-server

I am using LEFT JOIN three times in a query to display user information. For some reason, the second last LEFT JOIN affects the output of the SUM function.

I have tried removing the second last LEFT JOIN statement which returns the correct value. I don't see why it would change the value.

```sql
SELECT 
    [tbl_users].[id],
    [username],
    COUNT([tbl_password_resets].[id]) as passwordresets,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [tbl_files].[user_id] = [tbl_users].[id] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as uploads,
    COUNT([tbl_downloads].[id]) as downloads,
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [tbl_downloads].[liked] = 1 OR [tbl_downloads].[disliked] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FLOAT) / NULLIF(COUNT([tbl_downloads].[id]), 0) as ratio,
    [ban]
FROM 
    [tbl_users]
LEFT JOIN 
    [tbl_password_resets] ON [tbl_users].[id] = [tbl_password_resets].[user_id]
LEFT JOIN 
    [tbl_downloads] ON [tbl_users].[id] = [tbl_downloads].[user_id]
LEFT JOIN 
    [tbl_files] ON [tbl_files].[user_id] = [tbl_users].[id]
GROUP BY 
    [tbl_users].[id], [tbl_users].[username], [tbl_users].[ban]
```

The result for uploads is 9 instead of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any joined table is duplicating rows, that affects the result of COUNTs and SUMs. Comment out the aggregates and the GROUP BY and the JOINs for testing and see what happens with the row count when you build the query adding the JOINs one-by-one. The more rows fall into one group, the more values will be COUNTed and SUMmed.

Comment: I have done that already, they are not duplicating any rows because they're all LEFT JOINS.

Comment: @JohnDoe left join does not prevent duplicates. Any join can cause duplicates. Since you have not provided schema, sample data and expected output, you will not get a better answer than this one. If you did that, people could explain. Maybe I can phrase this answer differently: comment out the `GROUP BY` clause, and everything before the `FROM`. Insert `SELECT *` at the start. Now run the query and look at all the returned columns. Somewhere, there is one record joined to multiple records, so the value from the one record is being repeated, which is altering the result of summing it.

Comment: @Richardissimo good suggestion. Or he could add SELECT COUNT(*), start from the first table, then add them one-by-one to see if the number changes - I think it should.